# Matching tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to count the number of tags in the 'soup' from a beautifulsoup result. I'd like to use a regular expression but am having trouble.
The code Ive tried is as follows:

```
reg_exp_tag = re.compile("<[^>*>")
tags = re.findall(reg_exp_tag, soup(cast as a string))
```

but `re` will not allow `reg_exp_tag`, giving an unexpected end of regular expression error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Why on *earth* are you mis-parsing HTML with a broken regex when you've already parsed it properly with BeautifulSoup? Seriously, what the hell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `"<[^>]*>"` instead of `"<[^>*>"`?

(the class needs to be closed with a `]`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Been staring at it so long not seeing the simple typos!

Comment: Hehe, when programmer decided solve a problem with regex, he ends up with 2 problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you've already parsed the HTML with BeautifulSoup, why parse it again?  Try this:

```
num_tags = len(soup.findAll())
```

Comment: +1 no regex can possibly parse HTML correctly, which is why most people use BeautifulSoup. BeautifulSoup plus serialisation to HTML plus regex is just a bagful of wrong!